# SIGABRT - only happens in one folder

Tags: ios5, ios-simulator, sigabrt

I have the same project stored in two different folders for backup reasons. When I run the project from folder1, I get SIGABRT. From folder2 it runs ok.

Is there something I am missing or should I just consider it a bug and continue working from another folder?

Comment: The right way is to use zip-archives and Xcode snapshots for backups.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the app that is in the "bad folder" and click on your scheme, edit it and switch to debug type LLDB (maybe you have already done this and im wasting your time) and then run the app, look in the debug console for some extra information. I had a SIGABRT error and i did this and helped me locate the problem. Hope this helped. :)